# Laravel where clause with action before search

Tags: php, laravel

I got my model where I need to perform a search. I made sha256 hash of an ID available in the URL (I don't want to disclose real id that is stored in database) and now I need to retrieve model by that ID. Is there a way to do hashing before search ? What I mean exactly:

```
$hashed_id = ...;
Model::where('id',$hashed_id)->first();
```

Model ID is currently not hashed, so is there a way to hash it before I check it against my hash value in where clause ?

I realized that I can just create a new column with hashed value when I create model but this way would be better.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone ID is not integer in my case, it's UUID

Comment: Can you hash it in raw SQL ?

Comment: @EkinOf How would you do that  ?

Comment: You can't restore original value from hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try something like that :

```
Model::where(DB::raw('SHA2(id, 256)'), $hashed_id)->first();
```